# SQL SErver insert into causes error 515

Tags: sql-server, insert

I wrote the following query which inserts data from one table into another:

```
insert into [Softwarestatus]([Computer ID])
    select [ID] 
    from dbo.[Computer]
go
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column ID, PortalDB.dbo.Softwaretabelle, column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

It should auto create an `Id` (and insert this value to this id), or am I wrong?

Update works fine. I changed ID to something different (data from a different column etc)

I haven't found any solution to this problem, or what's wrong with this

Many thanks!

Edit:

The Struckture of the tables looks like this:

Computer:
ID (Primary key) | MAC| Computer

Softwarestatus
ID (Primary key) |Computer ID| Status

Comment: Execute this query `select [ID] from dbo.[Computer] where id is NULL` what is the output ?

Comment: please share the structure of the new table

Comment: The error message and the code have different tables. Is `Softwaretabelle` the table you're inserting into or is there a trigger that's doing that?

Comment: In SSMS, open the `Softwarestatus` table and right click on the `ID` column. Select properties and look for the Identity fields, approx 7 rows from the top. Does the Identity say `True` or `False`?

Comment: Jason : Identity is false

ahmed: the Output is empty...

Comment: James Z : I want to insert this Data in the Softwaretabelle

Answer (score 0):

The answer is kinda... meh. (You cant it as a beginner)

I needed to change the ID column, as Jason said, from false to true. Now it works. IDK why this doesent happens automaticly.

So:
Select Table -> Columns -> Main ID of your table -> Right click, then on change and go all down to the id specifications. Change Is Identity to true.

> But beware: I needed to recreate the Table!

Many thanks to Jason!